# Explain, please, these ++ and -- operations

Tags: javascript, increment, decrement

Why this code outputs 3, not 2?

```
var i = 1; 
i = ++i + --i; 
console.log(i);
```

I expected:

```
++i // i == 2
--i // i == 1
i = 1 + 1 // i == 2
```

Where I made mistake?

Comment: search stack overflow for `++` and `--` postfix and prefix operators

Comment: ++i = 2, then i = 2, --i = 1. Therefore 2+1=3 because javascript statements are evaluated from left to right.

Comment: By your own logic, i should be equal to 3.

Comment: I don't get it. You are stating yourself, that ++i evaluates to 2 and --i evaluates to 1, if you add up the two it's 3 - why would it be 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The changes occur in this order:

1. Increment `i` (to 2)
2. Take `i` for the left hand side of the addition (2)
3. Decrement `i` (to 1)
4. Take `i` for the right hand side of the addition (1)
5. Perform the addition and assign to `i` (3)

… and seeing you attempt to do this gives me some insight in to why JSLint doesn't like `++` and `--`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at it this way

x = (something)
x = (++i) + (something)
x = (2) + (something)
x = (2) + (--i)
x = (2) + (1)

The terms are evaluated from left to right, once the first ++i is evaluated it won't be re-evaluated when you change its value with --i.

Answer (score 2):

Your second line is adding 2 + 1.

In order, the interpreter would execute:

```
++i  // i == 2
+
--i  // i == 1
i = 2 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`++i` equals 2, `--i' equals 1. 2 + 1 = 3.

Answer (score 0):

You're a little off on your order of operations. Here's how it goes:

1. i is incremented by 1 (++i) resulting in a value of 2. This is
   stored in i.
2. That value of two is then added to the value of (--i)
   which is 1. 2 + 1 = 3

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use ++i the value of i is incremented and then returned. However, if you use i++, the value of i is returned and then incremented. [Reference](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?294799-I-vs-I)

Answer (score 0):

```
++$a   Increments $a by one, then returns $a.
$a++   Returns $a, then increments $a by one.
--$a   Decrements $a by one, then returns $a.
$a--   Returns $a, then decrements $a by one.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're expecting this code to work as if this is a reference object and the values aren't collected until the unary operations are complete. But in most languages an expression is evaluated first, so i returns the value of i, not i itself.

If you had ++(--i) then you'd be right.

In short, don't do this.

The result of that operation isn't defined the same in every language/compiler/interpreter. So while it results in `3` in JavaScript, it may result in `2` elsewhere.